# On every keypress event I am validation text box value and appending error message

Tags: jquery, append, keypress, onkeypress

```
$(street2_id).bind("keypress", function(e) {

            var street1_Length = $(street1_id).val().length;
            var street2_Length = $(street2_id).val().length;

            var total_street_char = street1_Length + street2_Length;

            if(total_street_char > 30){
                $(".shipping_street2").append('<div><span>Error Message</span></div>');
                $(street2_id).focus();

            }
        });
```

On every **keypress** event I am validating text box value and appending error message but the problem is on every keypress event the appended (multiple) error message generates. (I want it just once)

I want just one error message for the same.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Clear html before append. `$(".shipping_street2").html('');`

Comment: Hi Shree, there are multiple divs and input type in shipping_street2

Comment: Without seeing HTML it's impossible to answer  ? Can you add HTML with working snippet .

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gr9qyoes/

Comment: Put your error container in shipping_street_2. Give it an id, and then on every keypress clear the error container.

Comment: can you please show me the example of error container ? @Node_Ninja

Comment: Hello @Shree little_coder and Node_Ninja, Thanks a lot for your efforts ! :) I found the solution. thanks again for the helping hand :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Shree comment, we can clear first the elements inside the class `shipping_street2`. Also, it is better to use `on` `keydown` so that when backspace was pressed the error message will remove as well. Here is my try.

```js
$(street2_id).on("keydown", function(e) {
 
  var street1_Length = $(street1_id).val().length;
  var street2_Length = $(street2_id).val().length;

  var total_street_char = street1_Length + street2_Length;


  if (total_street_char > 30) {
    $(".shipping_street2").html('');
    $(".shipping_street2").append('<div class="error"><span>Error Message</span></div>');
    $(street2_id).focus();
  } else {
    $(".shipping_street2").html('');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.error span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shipping_street2"></div>
<input id="street1_id" type="text">
<input id="street2_id" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var once = false;

$(street2_id).bind("keypress", function(e) {

        var street1_Length = $(street1_id).val().length;
        var street2_Length = $(street2_id).val().length;

        var total_street_char = street1_Length + street2_Length;

        if(total_street_char > 30){
        if (!once || ! $('.street2_error_span').length) {
            $(".shipping_street2").append('<div><span>Error Message</span></div>');
            $(street2_id).focus();
            once = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

**[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/jquery-keypress-event-should-only-function-once/)**